# Melee or Ranged attacks by Monsters, no distinction in modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, ability-scores, ranged-attack

Weapons with the Thrown property can be utilised as both as Melee as well as Ranged weapons. When used as a Melee weapon, you base the attack+damage rolls on Strength, otherwise on Dexterity (unless it's a Finesse weapon, in which case you decide).

My question:

1. Why don't I see this reflected in Monster statblocks? I've been going through the MM, and never have I seen this reflected (ie. the attack and damage are not specified specifically for melee/ranged attacks). Is this to keep it simple, or shouldn't you make this distinction when it comes to Monsters? And thus:
2. Should I follow the attack roll and damage from the action as described, or calculate it differently depending on if the attack is a melee or ranged attack?

For example, looking at the [Ogre](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ogre) (MM p. 237), it reads for the Javelin:

> ***Javelin.*** *Melee or Ranged Weapon Attack:* +6 to hit, reach 5 ft. or range 30/120 ft., one target. *Hit:* 11 (2d6 + 4) piercing damage.

Since the Ogre has a +4 Str and a -1 Dex, the attack and damage rolls are clearly based on Strength. Now, what if this Ogre decides to hurl that Javelin at someone, should I use these numbers or figure out that the Ogre is a CR 2, thus has a proficiency bonus of +2, thus the Attack roll would become +1 (2-1) and the damage roll -1?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you see no distinction is that there isn't any: thrown attacks default to the same modifier the weapon uses for melee attacks. From the ["Weapon Properties"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) section of the Basic Rules on D&D Beyond:

> **Thrown.** If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon.

There is no reason to recalculate monster modifiers.

Comment: Can't believe I have read over that! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The description of the **Thrown** property, PHB, p. 147 contains the following sentence, emphasis mine:

> If the weapon is a melee weapon, **you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon**.

There simply is no difference between the (damage) modifier for melee and ranged attacks with the thrown weapon.

Javelins cannot be used with DEX in melee combat, therefore DEX **cannot** be used to calculate the attack modifier/damage for Javelins.

---

There's nothing preventing a monster to use one of it's melee weapons as (potentially improvised) thrown weapon, but they do not carry multiple weapons, unless *Ranged* is mentioned, see MM p. 10f:

> **ACTIONS**
>   When a monster takes its action, it can choose from the options in the Actions section of its stat block **or use one of the actions available to all creatures** [...] as described in the *Player's Handbook*.
>
> [...]
>
> **AMMUNITION**
>   A monster carries enough ammunition to make its ranged attacks. You can assume that a monster has 2d4 pieces of ammunition for a thrown weapon attack [...].